# Android: What's the difference between lockCanvas() and lockCanvas(null)?

Tags: android, surfaceview

The title says it quite clearly, though I'll give a code example just in case.  This is from the LunarLander sample in the Android SDK:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (mRun) {
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                    if (mMode == STATE_RUNNING) updatePhysics();
                    doDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The documentation for `lockCanvas()` says all pixels must be re-drawn, whereas `lockCanvas(Rect dirty)` says you're only required to re-draw pixels in `dirty`.  I see two possible interpretations of passing `null` to this function: it doesn't require any pixels to be re-drawn, or behaves in the same manner as `lockCanvas()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is open source

```
public Canvas lockCanvas() {
  return internalLockCanvas(null);
}
public Canvas lockCanvas(Rect dirty) {
  return internalLockCanvas(dirty);
}
```

Comment: No need to shame, now you know how android sources are usefull, you can use them for development, even to find out how things done in phone/contacts/email etc apps from android open source project